# socket programming based on UDP in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing code for UDP protcol implementation where in I have to break the file into chunks of 1024 bytes. Then calculate the checksum of each packet and put a sequence number and add them as header information and send the  packet to the receiver. I know to make the file into chunks and calculate checksum. But to concatenate the header info and the data packet do I  have to use memcat? Can anyone suggest me how can I do it in C?

Comment: can you give a bit more info? like what have u done till now? better to put your code if there is any...

Comment: You can use `sendmsg` to gather the header and packet data from separate buffers to avoid copying it.

Answer (score 0):

When loading a 1024-byte chunk of file data from the file, load it into a slightly larger buffer/array (say, a `char[1024+4+4]`, i.e. 1032 bytes).  Then you have 8 extra bytes of space in your buffer that you can write your sequence number and checksum into, before send()-ing the buffer.

You can either write the sequence number and checksum after the 1024 bytes of data, or `fread()` in the data to a memory location 8 bytes after the start of the buffer, and then write the sequence number and checksum at the top of the buffer (i.e. into the space before the just-loaded data begins).  Either way works fine (as long as the sender and receiver agree on the layout), although I find the second way a little easier to think about.